# How to test OBD-II device ( for car ) response on android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, obd-ii

Currently I am upgrading an android and iOS app that will show Car RPM, speed, turbo and other things using OBD-II device (bluetooth). Most of the code was written on an old app source code and I am using that code on a new screen.

The problem is that I don't have a device for testing (I have just used code from an old source code ). I have a text file that has the response returned by the device. How can I send that response to mobile app using any windows/mac software ?

I mean is there any software available that will allow to connect mobile app via bluetooth and then I can send response. eg RPM, SPEED etc ?

Here is a sample response that I want to send via bluetooth (PC) to mobile app.

```
,$OBD-RT=2,76,1193,-40,0,103,-26,75,15.29,12.0,48,29.41,0,581.3,14.7,0.00,3.70,0.000,0.855,0.000,0.000,0
,$OBD-RT=2,76,1181,-40,0,103,-26,75,18.82,12.0,48,38.43,0,581.3,14.7,0.00,3.67,0.000,0.855,0.000,0.000,0
,$OBD-RT=2,76,1183,-40,0,103,2,103,18.82,12.0,48,38.43,0,579.1,14.7,0.00,5.04,0.000,0.845,0.000,0.000,0
```

I have attached 1 screenshot of the app

[image]

So is any software available ( for OBD-II)  that will allow the mobile app to connect via bluetooth so I can send the response to the app ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such an emulator as far as I know and if there is, normally not so reliable. But there are some devices such as [Freematics](https://freematics.com/pages/products/) that can emulate the vehicle's OBD II. In such devices there is a lack of multiple response from emulated ECU. (which as I see in your app is necessary and you probably want to have 6 requests together).

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about developing an OBD2-app, you should acquire a hardware simulator, i.e. the DIAMEX OBD2 Simulator. It's the next best thing apart from using a real car.